# Spring Hadoop | Job not appearing on Job Tracker GUI

Tags: spring, hadoop

I'm using Spring for Apache Hadoop 1.0.0.M2 for my application. The application is packaged as a binary distribution using maven assembly plugin and run over the cluster using:
java -jar mlprocessor.jar

The manifest file in the jar includes reference to the Main class which loads the spring context file. The job executes fine and I see the results as well. However, there is no trace of this job on the Job Tracker GUI.

The logs show the following warning though:

```
WARN [org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader] - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I wanted to check whether anyone is aware of this issue, or there is something that I am missing.

Comment: Weather the job is submitted through spring or not, it should be transparent to the Hadoop cluster and should be visible in the JobTracker GUI. I think Spring should not be an issue here.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, I would believe the same too. But, it does not seem to be working like that. I tried running the wordcount example that comes bundled with spring-data-hadoop-0.9.0.RELEASE and had similar observation: the Job Tracker user interface didn't track this job.

Answer (score 0):

I did post the same question on Spring Hadoop forum (http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?131245-Job-not-appearing-on-JobTracker-user-interface) and received an answer there:

I was missing 'mapred.job.tracker' property configuration in hdp:configuration.  After changing the configuration to below, Job tracker UI was able to track this job.

```
<hdp:configuration>
    fs.default.name=${fs.default.name}
    mapred.job.tracker=${mapred.job.tracker}
</hdp:configuration>
```